# React Native Firebase App and AdMob version dependency problem

Tags: react-native, dependencies, admob, react-native-firebase

I want to use @react-native-firebase/admob to show ads in my react native application but I am getting dependency problem while trying to run my application in android emulator.

**Error**

```
> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/admob' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v11.5.0 but found v18.1.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
101 actionable tasks: 39 executed, 62 up-to-date
..\MyProject\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-67 Error:
        Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID@value value=(ca-app-pub-6771621836437859~7461252155) from AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-67
        is also present at [:react-native-firebase_admob] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-29 value=().
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:69 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID@value value=(ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX) from AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-67
        is also present at [:react-native-firebase_admob] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-29 value=().
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:69 to override.
```

**Dependencies**

| Package Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| react | 16.9.0 |
| react-native | 0.61.0 |
| @react-native-firebase/app | ^18.1.0 |
| @react-native-firebase/admob | ^11.5.0 |
| Other Packages... |  |

**My question:**
Is @react-native-firebase/admob not maintained? If so then what other package shall I use to show Ads?

Please do not suggest me to downgrade @react-native-firebase/app because I want to use the latest version.

**What I was planning to do and what I Got**

I was using old `react-native-firebase` package to use firebase functionalities but I started getting errors because all the packages were OLD so I decided to update all to their latest versions. After updating them to the latest version I got an error as described above in my question.

Let me know if this question is ambiguous.